# Composer Self-Update Error Exception "Permission Denied" when calling rename()

Tags: mysql, bash, composer-php

So, whenever i run `composer self-update` or `composer selfupdate` I get the following error:

[image: Output of the Composer Error]

> [ErrorException]
>     rename(/Users/jrobinson/.composer/cache/composer-temp.phar,/usr/local/bin/composer): Permission denied

I'm not too sure what's going on. I THINK i may had screwed up my **.bash_profile** file up. I wasn't having this issue prior to installing MySQL on my machine, and updating the first line in my **.bash_profile**.

I have looked at other articles, and I have tried reinstalling using the getcomposer.org commands on their download page. None of these solutions have fixed my problem. So please don't mark this as a repeat question as none of the solutions on SO have helped me solve this issue.

Here is my .bash_profile file contents.

```
export PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin"
export EDITOR='sub -w'
```

Here is the `ls -la` command run in the `/usr/local/bin` folder.

[image: Output of the ls la command in /usr/local/bin]

**Goal**

Be able to run the `composer self-update` command and the `mysql` command from my terminal at the end of all this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like Composer is installed in `/usr/local/bin`, so you probably did that as root. To update it, you also need to be a root - try with sudo:

```
sudo -H composer self-update
```

Comment: Thank you! Works just fine now!

Comment: @robo006 any change you can share something for widows too? I'm getting same error on windows but not able to update it